# jhat throwing unrecognized magic number

Tags: java, jmap, jhat

I am trying to analyse a heap dump taken from a java process that ran into memory issues. The dump was taken using jmap. I am using jhat on the dump file - I am getting

`java.io.IOException: Unrecognized magic number: 169897589
        at com.sun.tools.hat.internal.parser.Reader.readFile(Reader.java:94)
        at com.sun.tools.hat.Main.main(Main.java:159)`

Both jdk 1.6 and 1.7 give the same error. I am running the jhat on my Windows machine locally (after copying the dump file over ) and the dump file was taken on Linux server.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can we see some code so we can have any idea of what you're doing wrong?

Comment: my question is about the jhat throwing the error - the source code should not be directly required for the question I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code for [com.sun.tools.hat.internal.parser.Reader](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/tools/hat/internal/parser/Reader.java), you'll see that it's looking for the magic number [0x4a415641](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/tools/hat/internal/parser/HprofReader.java#HprofReader.0MAGIC_NUMBER).

This value is used to help identify valid heap dump files. `jmap` should append this value as the first four bytes of any heap dump file it creates.

I'd suggest opening up your heap dump in a hex editor and checking to see whether the first four bytes are `0x4a415641`. Check this for the file on both your Linux and Windows machine. Perhaps the file is getting corrupted when you transfer the file.

Answer (score 1):

probably, U got the wrong way to generate jvm dump file.
the error occurs when using jmap -histo {pid} > dump.log.

try

```
   jmap -dump:live;file=filename pid
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are providing a zip file (.gz or .tar.gz) to the jhat tool. That's why it is not able to verify the hprof header. Recently, I ran across the same situation. My heap dump was captured on a Linux server in .tar.gz format and I supplied as is to get the same error which you got. After untarring the file, jhat was able to analyze the .hprof file.